# In which file Joomla 3.x generating the "edit article" links for authors Front End?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

If you are allowed to edit the articles in Joomla, near the each article in the list, an "edit" button is present. How can I find, how that "edit" button generated? I just want to add some parameters. (I'm using a Front End for edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php

```
        <?php if ($canEdit) : ?>
        <li class="edit-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

You can override this in your template's html folder.

This script calls a function under components/com_content/helpers/icon.php to generate the icon.

You should not override this helper file.  If you need to change what that function is doing, filter the content it generates after it has been run, whether via a plug-in or the default.php file.